# Nodejs parameter resolution and printing

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to debug my mobile website which is running on Nodejs.
In some part there are those lines:

```
var log_line = {accessCount: accessCount, x: x, time: t};
logstream.write(JSON.stringify(log_line));
```

Which are suppose to log parts of the users page request. The path is defined as `app.get('/:x?.:y?.:z?', function(req, res){ )`.

For some users this works fine, but for others in the log I only find a line saying "`{"accessCount": 1, "time": "10/10/10"}`". How is it possible? shouldn't it at least printed the `x` without anything beside it? what could cause this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `x` is `undefined`, it won't get printed:

```
> JSON.stringify({x:undefined})
'{}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution to get over it. Change the code as

```
   if (!x) {
    x = "NOT_DEFINED" // or your own place holder value
   }
   var log_line = {accessCount: accessCount, x: x :, time: t};
```

or more terse would be

```
   var log_line = {accessCount: accessCount, x: x ? x : "NOT_DEFINED", time: t};
```